# How to call MSBuild tasks from FinalBuilder?

Tags: msbuild, build, build-automation, msbuild-task, finalbuilder

The only way I see now is to create xml file for MSBuild containing needed tasks invocations and then run MSBuild directly by calling "Execute Program" action. Is there any standard way of doing this using FinalBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FinalBuilder 6 you can use a MSBuild Task. However to be honest in our build script I found that using a batch file and the 'Execute Program' to be a better solution.

**Edit:** Quickly doing some reading on this topic I now remember why I used a batch file. The FB6 MSBuild action is a little counterintuitive as not all the properties are accessible from the 'default view' and you need to change to the 'property grid'.

**Update:** From your comment; if you want to run an individual MSBuild task and not use the 'Execute Program' action then you will need to create your own FB action. I have never created an custom action myself but apparently they are really simple.

This is the batch file that I used:

```
@ECHO off
SET Action=%1
SET Configuration=%2
SET Platform=x86
SET CommonTools=%VS90COMNTOOLS%
SET SourceDir=%CD%\..\..
SET SolutionFilename=Solution.sln
SET MSBuild=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe

IF "%Action%" == "" SET Action=Rebuild
IF "%Configuration%" == "" SET Configuration=Release

:BUILD
%MSBuild% "%SourceDir%\%SolutionFilename%" /v:m /t:%Action% /p:Configuration=%Configuration% /p:DenEnvDir="%CommonTools%..\IDE\" /p:SolutionDir="%SourceDir%" /p:Platform=%Platform%

:END
ECHO.
ECHO ErrorLevel: %ERRORLEVEL%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: FB does not have MSBuild Task. It has "MSBuild project" action using it looks like workaround. Btw, why do you think that property grid is less intuitive than a seperate script?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I do not have FB installed at the moment. It must have been a 'MSBuild Project' that I was thinking of. The comment about the property grid was specific to editing actions in FB; especially with MSBuild project. I use property grids frequently in software that I develop as I need to present a lot of dynamic data to users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just run an msbuild task from within another application without instantiating the msbuild environment on which it depends. You will need an msbuild project file at the very least.

Comment: I undarstand, but my question was is there is any built-in functionality in FinalBuilder to do this for me. E.g. they have "Run MSBuild project" action, why there is no "Run MSBuild task" action?